# Index has no effect on intersect query using &&

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database that was created via the QGIS DB Manager using the following command. The `geom` column contains about 500,000 hexagon polygons, while the `centroid` column stores the centroid of those hexagons. The `id` is just a unique value assigned to each.

```
CREATE TABLE public.hex15p625
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Hex15p625_id_seq"'::regclass),
  geom geometry(Polygon,4326),
  centroid geometry(Point,4326),
  CONSTRAINT "Hex15p625_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I am using the following query to return as GeoJSON any hexagons that fall within a bounding box:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geom, ST_AsGeoJSON(centroid) AS centroid
FROM public.hex15p625
WHERE 
  ST_Shift_Longitude(public.hex15p625.geom) && 
  ST_Shift_Longitude(ST_MakeEnvelope(-86.0057, 48.8199, -85.6854, 48.9955, 4326));
```

To speed up the queries, I created two indices, though only one is used in the use-case above:

```
CREATE INDEX "sidx_Hex15p625_geom"
  ON public.hex15p625
  USING gist
  (geom);
ALTER TABLE public.hex15p625 CLUSTER ON "sidx_Hex15p625_geom";
```

And this one, which I'm just putting here for the sake of completeness:

```
CREATE INDEX "sidx_Hex15p625_centroid"
  ON public.hex15p625
  USING gist
  (centroid);
```

When doing the above query, I found that queries took about 700ms before, and 700ms after I made the spatial indices. To double check, I make a copy of the above table, removed both indices, and ran an identical query against both and received almost exactly the same result.

Is there something preventing the query from using the index I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not entirely sure (I have never had the issue), it is most likely the use of `ST_Shift_Longitude()`. The `gist` index works with the boxes of the original geometries, but you expressly shift geometries in the western hemisphere using the function. You could try to build an index on the function result and see if that helps:

```
CREATE INDEX "sidx_Hex15p625_geom_shift"
  ON public.hex15p625
  USING gist (ST_Shift_Longitude(geom));
```